# ¿Como imprimir en consola el mensaje del catch, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
 function agregarCatalogos(idPedido, CodigoInventario, Cantidad) {
             myApp.showIndicator();
            return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `https://url/api/AppUpdateProductoCatalogo?IDPedido=${parseInt(idPedido)}&CodigoInventario=${CodigoInventario}&Cod_Agencia=${cod_agencia}&Cantidad=${parseInt(Cantidad)}`,
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                    }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //$('.catalogos_disponibles').remove();
                    //$('.catalogos_disponibles').remove();
                    pedidoProforma(idPedido, tipo_envio, cod_agencia, cod_depto, producto_gratis,equipo_socionuevo, cod_cliente);
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                }).catch(function (Error) {
                   console.log(Error);
                    myApp.alert("Es un Catálogo por cada compra llave que realices; no puedes seleccionar más");
                    el_product_quantity.text(parseInt(el_product_quantity.text())-1);
                    myApp.hideIndicator();
                })
            })
    }
```

Dicha funcion me da el siguiente mensaje como que fuera un error. Ese mensaje en la imagen se debe mostrar el catch, pero no se como imprimirlo en la consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muy agradecido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta `console.log(Error.Error)`

Comment: me sale undefined, incluso probe: catch(function (e) {console.log(e.Error)}); pero no funciono

Comment: pega lo que te sale en consola para verlo mejor, no en imagen

Comment: Me refería al `console.log(Error)` cópialo y pégalo como texto, no como imagen

Comment: Intenta así: `}).catch(function (error) {
                   console.log(error.response);`  o bien de este modo: `}).catch(function (error) {
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(error));`

Comment: solamente sale undefined.

Comment: ¿Si lo pones así también?: **`}).catch(function (error) { console.log(JSON.stringify(error));`**

Comment: Cedano, utilizando console.log(error.response), me ha servido, ya que de esta forma pude acceder al objeto que devuelve el mensaje. Era asi:  console.log(error.response.data.Error); me ha servido tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: [Revisa esto](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors), ellos recomiendan ir clasificando los tipos de posibles respuestas de error. Quizá te convenga seguir las recomendaciones de los creadores. De todos modos, al tener un error 500, deberías revisar el código en el servidor.